# how to get gcc/gpp 6 to 9 onto a Xenial system from behind a firewall with apt and gpg?

Tags: 16.04, proxy, gcc, gnupg, g++

i tried getting compilers higher than gcc/gpp-5 for Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).

i added these lines to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial main
```

when running "apt update" afterwards i got this:

```
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
 The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8CF63AD3F06FC659
```

Then i tried adding the keys:

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
Executing: /tmp/tmp.hQqulW3vSQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-key
1E9377A2BA9EF27F
> gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: key not found
gpg: keyserver communications error: bad public key
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad public key

# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 8CF63AD3F06FC659
Executing: /tmp/tmp.9sbMVJgRDb/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-key
8CF63AD3F06FC659
gpg: requesting key F06FC659 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 8CF63AD3F06FC659 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: key not found
gpg: keyserver communications error: bad public key
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad public key
```

How to simply get a set of more recent compilers to this platform?

i found out its hard to achieve something like that when behind a firewall. standard recipes wont work, even "sudo -E" failed for me. and i currently have no clue how to improve debug prints for the apt-* tool set.

Comment: updated so that the GPG and firewall core problem is a bit more visible in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(development of this solution is partly based on the dialog between N0rbert and me in his initial proposal)

the understanding of the problem evolved to the point where "gpg" access was found as the problematic/dangling operation. the comment of user "nobar" was most helpful for getting the final clue:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

In this scenario, the message is a cryptic way of telling you that the download failed.
```

see those topic in full size discussed there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338721/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found

now for doing a work around to solve the issue in the topic right here...

go to http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/ - for each of the missing keys (BA9EF27F / F06FC659) do:

- enter each missing key with a "0x" prefix to the offered input box
- select radio button for "Get verbose index of matching keys"
- click button "Search for a key"
- in the resulting page click the link in the "pub" line and save the target web page to your download folder (i used the short keyId and a *.txt extension; in fact its a HTML file content, but that's a pretty don't care thing)
- run the follwing command as root for each of the downloaded files:

  ```
  apt-key add ***name-of-the-file***
  ```

when the above is done two times (for each key once) then run this for checking if it worked:

```
apt update
```

the results should contain besides several other lines also something like these lines:

```
Get:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main Sources [13.4 kB]
Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [86.8 kB]
Get:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [85.1 kB]
Get:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [14.4 kB]
Get:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial/main Sources [12.1 kB]
Get:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [79.7 kB]
Get:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [78.4 kB]
Get:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [15.7 kB]
```

the final operation is about installing the extra gcc versions of your choice:

```
apt install gcc-6 g++-6
apt install gcc-7 g++-7
apt install gcc-8 g++-8
apt install gcc-9 g++-9
```

This finally succeeded for me. All items were obtained from  http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu in the amd64 repository version. I suppose i need to swap the lines in the sources.list file if i ever want to set a higher priority on the other PPA.

Checking the version of the installed gcc binaries returns as of now this texts:

```
# gcc-6 --version
gcc-6 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# gcc-7 --version
gcc-7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# gcc-8 --version
gcc-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-16ubuntu3~16.04) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# gcc-9 --version
gcc-9 (Ubuntu 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~16.04) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Checking the version of the installed g++ binaries returns as of now this texts:

```
# g++-6 --version
g++-6 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# g++-7 --version
g++-7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~16.04~ppa1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# g++-8 --version
g++-8 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-16ubuntu3~16.04) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# g++-9 --version
g++-9 (Ubuntu 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~16.04) 9.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**Update:**
These command (as of now) evidently uses the Jonathon PPA:

```
# apt install clang
```

At present the command results in this versions:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu3~trusty5 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

# clang++ --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu3~trusty5 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: It is great, that you have a solution :) I removed my comment about disclaimer.

Comment: its great that the discussion with you brought up the index to the core problem to my attention. thanks.

Comment: others have similar problems - it seems like gpg might use a port and protocol that is different from http/https/ftp (as normally a proxy setup will offer for usage).
see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361213/unable-to-add-gpg-key-with-apt-key-behind-a-proxy - even some pure command-line work-arounds/solutions are included - they protocol in question is abbreviated with "hkps".